# Por que esse erro

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, tomcat

Alguém pode por favor me explicar esse erro?

```
<%

    String[][] mesa = new String[30][30];

    out.println("");
    for(int i=30; i>=0; i--)
    {
        for(int n=0; n<((302)+1); n++)
        {
            out.print("-");
        }
        out.println("<br>");
        for(int j=0; j<30; j++)
        {
            mesa[i][j]=" ";
            out.print("|" + mesa[i][j]);
        }
        out.print("|<br>");
    }

    for(int n=0; n<((302)+1); n++)
    {
        out.print("-");
    }
    out.println("<br>");

%>
```

[image: Esse é o erro que aparece no navegador]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você declarou a variável mesa com 30 linhas e colunas, então o range de acesso para essa variável é de 0 até 29, contudo no laço "for(int i=30; i>=0; i--)", você acessa a variável na posição 30 causando a exceção, tente mudar a inicialização de i para 29.